# Assets of Nuxt project on Github pages not being displayed

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, nuxt.js

As noted in the documentation, I changed the base route in order to serve the assets in the right way, doing it like so:

```
const config = {
  // Changes the website's base to work on Github pages
  routerBase: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'gh_pages' ? '/my-app/' : '/'
};

module.exports = {
 router: {
    base: config.routerBase
  }
}
```

With a background picture in `index.vue` in the `pages` folder displayed like so:

```
.home {
  background: url('/background.jpg') no-repeat bottom fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

Therefore the path should be `/my-app/background.jpg`, but the image is not displayed as if it tried to find it following the route `/`.

What am I doing wrong? Please note that the `index.html` deployed from the `dist` folder contains the right base like so: `<base href="/my-app/">`

Comment: Dont use absolute path in css, base dont work for css

Comment: How should I define the background image then in order to have the base applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the url path to `~/static/background.jpg` solved the issue, odd when I'm trying to access a static asset from the static folder, where `/background.jpg` should have been enough.